# Why is my radio input element inside a custom component not working properly with reactive forms?

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, reactive

I am trying to write a component that provides a reusable custom radio input field.  I have created a real simple sample in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsvzyn) that I hope communicates what I am trying to do. This simple app does not work as expected and I have not yet figured out why.  Would love someone else's eyes on this.

**The custom radio component's html**

```html
<div [formGroup]="frm">
  <label [for]="id">
  <input [id]="id" type="radio" [value]="value" [formControlName]="cn">{{label}}
  </label>
</div>
```

**Custom radio component's typescript**

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-radio',
  templateUrl: './radio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio.component.css']
})
export class RadioComponent {
  @Input() frm: FormGroup;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() cn: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

**HTML where custom radio component is being used**

```html
<form [formGroup]="frm">
  <app-radio id="rc1" [frm]="frm" label="Yes" value="Yes" cn="question" ></app-radio>
  <app-radio id="rc2" [frm]="frm" label="No" value="No" cn="question"></app-radio>
</form>
<hr>
<h3>Form Data</h3>
<pre>{{frm.value | json}}
```

**Typescript for html using the custom radio component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  frm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.frm = this.fb.group({
    question: ['Yes', Validators.required]
  });
  }
}
```

**Expected Behavior**

1. Expect the following initial screen:

   [image: Expected Result]
2. When I click on the No radio after initial screen, the Yes radio gets unchecked and the No radio gets checked.
3. When I click on the No radio after initial screen, the form data shows that the question property has a value of "No".
4. Subsequent option clicks unchecks the other option and checks the clicked option.
5. Subsequent option clicks change the form value for question field.

**Actual Behavior**

1. Success
2. Failed.  Both options are checked.
3. Success
4. Failed. Nothing seems to happen when I click on either option.
5. Failed. Nothing seems to happen when I click on either option.

**Other Observations**
I was surprised to not find value and name attributes on the resulting input elements as seen in a screenshot I took from Chrome Dev Tool:

[image]

I would be so grateful if someone could lend me some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjakva) that I believe fulfills your behavior expectations.
I've added `[checked]="frm.get(cn).value === value"`.

**radio.component.html**

```html
<div [formGroup]="frm">
  <label [for]="id">
    <input [id]="id" type="radio" [value]="value" [formControlName]="cn" [checked]="frm.get(cn).value === value">{{label}}
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm still doing a bit of digging myself, but I suspect the issue is that the outer `formGroup` directive in `app.component.html` can't locate the nested radio inputs created by `RadioComponent`.

Comment: I am still left wondering why my code didn't work as is.  Your theory makes sense to me and I am going to research that as well.  Please post back here if you find out anything.  I will as well.  For the time being, I am accepting this as the answer because you made my sample work with minor modifications.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach versus implementing the ControlValueAccessor for my component.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

## **Why my Stackblitz sample did not work?**

The answer to why my Stackblitz sample does not work as expected is found in
the source code for RadioControlRegistry
(packages/forms/src/directives/radio_control_value_accessor.ts).

```
  select(accessor: RadioControlValueAccessor) {
    this._accessors.forEach((c) => {
      if (this._isSameGroup(c, accessor) && c[1] !== accessor) {
        c[1].fireUncheck(accessor.value);
      }
    });
  }

  private _isSameGroup(
      controlPair: [NgControl, RadioControlValueAccessor],
      accessor: RadioControlValueAccessor): boolean {
    if (!controlPair[0].control) return false;
    return controlPair[0]._parent === accessor._control._parent &&
        controlPair[1].name === accessor.name;
  }
```

When you click on a unchecked radio control, this select function is called.  It will call fireUncheck for other radio controls with the same name property AND the same parent.

That last part is the problem.  Each custom radio control has a different parent.  Parent here refers to an instance of a FormGroupDirective.  Each custom radio control is wrapped with a div that gets a new instance of FormGroupDirective.  The fireUncheck never gets called.

## **Solution:**

If somehow I could make the parents be equal in this scenario, it would work.

I found that I could by using formControl directive instead of the formControlName directive in the radio component.

I have created a modified version of the [Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hui63l?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html).  I replaced formGroup and formControlName directives with the formControl directive.  Works like a charm.

Here is the modified code:

**The custom radio component's html**

```html
<div>
  <label [for]="id">
  <input [id]="id" type="radio" [value]="value" [formControl]="ctrl">{{label}}
  </label>
</div>
```

**Custom radio component's typescript**

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-radio',
  templateUrl: './radio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio.component.css']
})
export class RadioComponent {
  @Input() ctrl: FormControl;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

**HTML where custom radio component is being used**

```html
<form [formGroup]="frm">
  <app-radio id="rc1" label="Yes" value="Yes" [ctrl]="frm.get('question')" ></app-radio>
  <app-radio id="rc2" label="No" value="No" [ctrl]="frm.get('question')"></app-radio>
</form>
<hr>
<h3>Form Data</h3>
<pre>{{frm.value | json}}
```

**Typescript for html using the custom radio component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  frm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.frm = this.fb.group({
    question: ['Yes', Validators.required]
  });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is that your two radio buttons are not connected. I just tried your Stackblitz example and for me the initial value is Yes and when I click No, both are checked.

As far as I know, radio buttons need to share the same *name* property to be connected as also documented by [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp). You could try the following, which uses the name *question*:

```html
<form [formGroup]="frm">
  <app-radio id="rc1" name="question" [frm]="frm" label="Yes" value="Yes" cn="question" ></app-radio>
  <app-radio id="rc2" name="question" [frm]="frm" label="No" value="No" cn="question"></app-radio>
</form>
```

To be honest: I do not quite get what you are trying to achieve with your custom component here. You could also go with native radio buttons:

```html
<form [formGroup]="frm">
  <input type="radio" id="rc1" name="question" label="Yes" value="Yes" cn="question" >
  <input type="radio" id="rc2" name="question" label="No" value="No" cn="question">
</form>
```

Note: I've removed *[frm]="frm"* here.

And if you need custom CSS, you could overwrite that as well:

```css
input {
    color: red;
}
```

**EDIT: Using the RadioControlValueAccessor**

The official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor) shows an example of using radioButtons inside a reactive form similar to what you do (except for the custom component wrapping the radioButton input field).

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="beef" > Beef
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="lamb"> Lamb
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="fish"> Fish
</form>
```

Here they all use the same formControlName *food* to link the radioButtons. In your question, this will be *question* to match your formControl.

Comment: Thank you @gerstams.  There is a longer story behind why I want to wrap a radio input.  This is not the actual code that I am working on.  I simplified it to the minimum yet still retaining the essence of what I am trying to do.  I appreciate your question and will think about the "why" of my approach.  I am still interested in making this example work.

Comment: From angular's documentation and source code, the RadioControlValueAccessor will add the name attribute if it is missing using the value provided as the formControlName.  Am I correct?

Comment: I'm afraid that for now I can only lead you to the angular documentation of the [RadioControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor) where they use formControlName instead of name. I've editted my answer to reflect this

Comment: The info you provided here was info that I already knew.  Although it did not help me progress at this time, I think that this answer is helpful in general for other readers and would have been helpful earlier in my research.  So I am going vote this up.

Comment: Sorry that it did not help and thanks for the upvote.